# How to Create Dynamic Menu bar in Laravel using Database

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller, middleware

initially, I created the static navigation bar but now I want to improve navigation bar as Dynamically.

in there im try function inside the Controller but it was not success because that view manage only one route.i need to that view in every pages of my web.

SideMenuController.php:

```
<?php 
   namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
   
   use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
   use App\admins; 
   use DB; 

  class SideMenuController extends Controller { 
    public function index(){ 
      $details = DB::SELECT("SELECT Name FROM admins"); 
      return view('layout', compact('details')); 
    } 
  }
```

web.php:

```
 Route::get('/user/test','SideMenuController@index');
```

test.blade.php :

Order 
           
          
             @foreach($details as $value)

{{ $value->Name }}

@endforeach

Error Exception

> (3/3) ErrorException Undefined variable: details (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ERP\ERP_LAR\resources\views\test.blade.php) (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ERP\ERP_LAR\resources\views\test.blade.php)

Comment: SideMenuController.php


<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\admins;
use DB;

class SideMenuController extends Controller
{


    public function index(){
   
    $details = DB::SELECT("SELECT Name  FROM admins");
    

      return view('layout', compact('details'));
}
}


---------------------------------------------------
web.php

Route::get('/user/test','SideMenuController@index');

Comment: Please edit your code into your question instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: What does $details in test.blade.php contains. Can you print_r this and post it here?

Comment: $details is passed the variable from SideMenuController otherwise result of the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

For first take a look at the [blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade) engine that is in Laravel.

The idea is that you will create a value in an controller and past this to the view. Here you will extract the value and place the right value to the right place. With blade you can even make a separate navigation.php and yield them in every view you need it.

Comment: How to fetch data from database and how to pass the view without route

Comment: You fetch the data in your controller and pass it to a view. All the information can been found on the laravel [website][https://laravel.com/docs/5.6]. Here you also can find how to use models and databases.

Answer (score -3):

There are many ways to solve the problem.

1. You can make a separate php file in your project like "navbar.php" and include it in by `<?php include('navbar.php'); ?>`
2. you can also use classes but it is harder.

Comment: How to fetch data from database and how to pass the view without route

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).